# VBA extra column search

Tags: excel, vba

I need to add PW to the below code ie RDG1, PW, Sewer Works, Pass. The extra column will be column D, cheers.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    .Range("D5").Value = Counts("RDG1", "Sewer Works")
    .Range("E5").Value = Counts("RDG1", "Sewer Works", "PASS")
    .Range("F5").Value = Counts("RDG1", "Sewer Works", "FAIL")

    'other counts here

End With



'Get row counts from sheet2
'  Optional 3rd parameter for PASS/FAIL
Function Counts(v1 As String, v2 As String, Optional v3 As String = "") As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
        Set rng1 = .Range("C7:C10000")
        Set rng2 = .Range("G7:G10000")
        Set rng3 = .Range("I7:I10000")
        If Len(v3) > 0 Then
            Counts = Application.CountIfs(rng1, v1, rng2, v2, rng3, v3)
        Else
            Counts = Application.CountIfs(rng3, v1, rng2, v2)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: @brax. This code was given to me to search 3 columns but I would like to modify it to search an extra column. I know very little about coding...obviously :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested - you should get the general pattern...

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    .Range("D5").Value = Counts("RDG1", "PW", "Sewer Works")
    .Range("E5").Value = Counts("RDG1", "PW", "Sewer Works", "PASS")
    .Range("F5").Value = Counts("RDG1", "PW", "Sewer Works", "FAIL")

    'other counts here

End With



'Get row counts from sheet2
'  Optional 4rd parameter for PASS/FAIL
Function Counts(v1 As String, v2 As String, v3 As String, Optional v4 As String = "") As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
        Set rng1 = .Range("C7:C10000")
        Set rng2 = .Range("D7:D10000")
        Set rng3 = .Range("G7:G10000")
        Set rng4 = .Range("I7:I10000")
        If Len(v4) > 0 Then
            Counts = Application.CountIfs(rng1, v1, rng2, v2, rng3, v3, rng4, v4)
        Else
            Counts = Application.CountIfs(rng1, v1, rng2, v2, rng3, v3)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: I got Expected End Sub error, so I put Function at the top and after the first End With, but now it gets Run time error 9, subscript out of Range at With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2). I have the data on sheet 2 and sheet 1 blank. Any suggestions, cheers

Comment: Fixed that, I was using it in my Personal, I created a workbook and it worked. What do I need to change to make it work in Personal.

Comment: I changed it to With Sheets(1), With Sheets(2) and it appears to work....is that correct?

Comment: If those are the correct sheets then it should be fine - it will default to the activeworkbook if you don't specify one